# Удалить элементы списка по условию

Tags: python, list, список

Есть список

```
lst = [0, 95, 0, 76, 0, 23, 68, 0, 23, 156, 95]
```

Требуется удалить каждый элемент, следующий за `0`

чтобы получить на выходе:

```
new_lst = [0,0,0,68,0,156,95]
```

Метод `str.index()` не помогает мне, так как возвращает только первое совпадение, а c `enumerate` пока не получается.

Answer (score 6):

```
lst = [0, 95, 0, 76, 0, 23, 68, 0, 23, 156, 95]
# Поскольку перед первым элементом 
# нет ничего (и нуля в том числе, что соответствует условию), 
# то он добавляется в любом случае.
# К тому-же при i == 0, i - 1 == -1 исключения не будет,
# так-как элемент с индексом -1 присутствует в списке,
# это последний элемент списка 


# Через цикл

new_list = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if i == 0 or lst[i - 1] != 0:
        new_list.append(lst[i])
print(new_list)

# Через генератор

print([lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)) if i == 0 or lst[i - 1] != 0])
```

Comment: `[lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)) if ([1] + lst)[i] != 0]`

Answer (score 6):

Ещё одно решение:

```
res = lst[:1] + [b for a,b in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if a]

print(res)
# [0, 0, 0, 68, 0, 156, 95]
```

[@АндрейNOP предложил более лаконичный и более изящный вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900102/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8e/900227?noredirect=1#comment1476535_900227):

```
res = [b for a,b in zip([1] + lst, lst) if a]
```

Comment: `[b for a,b in zip([1] + lst, lst) if a]`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, интересный вариант! Почему бы вам не добавить его в качестве ответа? ;)

Comment: Да это по сути модификация вашего ответа, поэтому написал здесь

Answer (score 3):

Из-за костыля с первым элементом не хотел писать ответ, но стало интересно, сможет ли кто-нибудь подсказать более изящное решение

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


lst = [0, 95, 0, 76, 0, 23, 68, 0, 23, 156, 95]
new_lst = [j for i, j in pairwise([None] + lst) if i != 0]
```

Comment: Мне мой [pairs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1226428/416121) кажется изящнее.

Comment: Конкатенацию у вас можно заменить на `itertools.chain`. На одну копию меньше и возможность работать с любыми `iterables`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy мой взят из [документации библиотеки itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Comment: Я про `[None] + lst`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да, ваш вариант действительно изящен.

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще один вариант решения, для коллекции:

**Update** - обернул в try, чтобы отлавливать исключение StopIteration

```
lst = [0, 95, 0, 76, 0, 23, 68, 0, 23, 156, 95]
seq = iter(lst)
newlst=[]
try:
    for _ in seq:
        newlst.append(_)
        if _==0:
            next(seq)
except StopIteration:
    pass
print(newlst)
```

Answer (score 2):

В Питоне богатая библиотека, но методов для обработки последовательных пар из `iterable` не хватает. Наверное, потому что вариаций много, и непонятно как их все собрать вместе. Три примера:

1. просто пары `[1, 2, 3] -> (1, 2), (2, 3)`
2. циклические пары `[1, 2, 3] -> (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1)`
3. неполная первая пара `[1, 2, 3] -> (None, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)`

Ещё есть неполная последняя пара и что там ещё в голову придёт.

Нам нужен третий вариант. Удобно что он работает с любым `iterable`, не только со списком:

```
def pairs(seq):
    prev = None
    for item in seq:
        yield prev, item
        prev = item

lst = [0, 95, 0, 76, 0, 23, 68, 0, 23, 156, 95]

print([b for a, b in pairs(lst) if a != 0])
```

> ```
> [0, 0, 0, 68, 0, 156, 95]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [0, 95, 0, 76, 0, 23, 68, 0, 23, 156, 95]

def cut_after_zero(lst):
    index = 0
    while True:
        try:
            index = lst[:-1].index(0, index)
        except ValueError:
            return lst
        index += 1
        lst.pop(index)

print(cut_after_zero(lst))  # [0, 0, 0, 68, 0, 156, 95]
```

Answer (score 1):

Без библиотек и итераторов, с забытым циклом `while True:`

```
lst = [0, 95, 0, 76, 0, 23, 68, 0, 23, 156, 95]
zeros = 0
while True:
    try:
        zeros = lst.index(0,zeros)+1
        lst.pop(zeros)
    except:
        break
```

а также без создания новых списков...
))
Только сча увидел, что есть похожее решение.
Но - мое понятнее мне и короче.

Comment: Он квадратичный. А можно решить за линейное время и не для списка а для любого `iterable`. :(

Answer (score 0):

1. с помощью filter и map можно удалить ненужные элементы из исходного списка

```
lst = [0, 95, 0, 76, 0, 23, 68, 0, 23, 156, 95]

# поиск индексов нужных элементов
delindex = list(filter(lambda i: lst[i-1]==0, range(1,len(lst)))) # здесь будут индексы удаляемых элементов

# удаление происходит в порядке от большего индекса к меньшему, для этого сортировка списка индексов
delindex.sort(reverse=True)

# удаление элементов
dellist = list(map(lambda d: lst.pop(d), delindex)) # здесь значения удалённых элементов

print(lst) # изменённый исходный список
```

с помощью полученных второстепенных списков можно восстановить исходный (если нужно конечно)

2. или сформировать новый список с помощью filter и map так

```
lst = [0, 95, 0, 76, 0, 23, 68, 0, 23, 156, 95]

newindex = [0]+list(filter(lambda i: lst[i-1]!=0, range(1,len(lst))))
newlist = list(map(lambda n: lst[n], newindex))

print(newlist)
```